# How can I check a string for multiple specific characters in java

Tags: java

I need to check a string to see if it contains any one of these characters (#, $, %, &) in java. I need to check for all 4 at the same time, with out a loop if possible and without regex. I am using this to verify validity of an email address so I cant just check for special characters as the email contains the @. Is there a way to use the .contains method with a switch statement?

Comment: what have u tried so far? Like we are not here to do your homework

Comment: Dude try to find out the answer through your own experiments and imaginations, why im not giving a code example and allowing you to copy is that then you will be used to use web rathar than your own brain. there is a stage for all the developers where you bearly understand things, at that stage you need to read, watch video tutorials, do your own homework to understand the fundementals of programming and that is the only way you can improve yourself and after that theree is a stage where things are complecated and need help, that is the time you should actually ask for help here

Answer (score 2):

Given a `String` `str`, and no loops or regular expressions you could presumable call [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) with a series of boolean ands like

```
if (str.contains("#") && str.contains("$") && str.contains("%")
        && str.contains("&")) {
     System.out.printf("%s contains #$%%&%n", str);
} else {
     System.out.printf("%s does not contain #$%%&%n", str);
}
```

Comment: `&&` instead of `||`? Looks like OP is checking whether the string contains any of the specified characters.

Comment: I need to check for all 4 at the same time, ? this is the reason for `&&` I suppose

Comment: @Elliott, Can Regex suffice the need here ? `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");` Negative pattern matching ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri From the question: _I need to check a string to see if it contains any one of these character_

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, think he has two contradictory statements :D ;)

Comment: @VinayVeluri Sure, but OP also said *without regex*.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [String.contains(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: ` Is there a way to use the .contains method with a switch statement?` I think OP knows `.contains` and he is asking `how` to use it

Comment: Using a regex would be the shortest, easiest way to do it `[\#\$\%\&]`. I dont see an obvious efficient way to use `switch-case`

Answer (score 0):

`String.subString(String foo)` allows you to search for specific case sensitive characters.

`Foo.subString(String.ignoreCase("bar")` will search `foo` for the string of characters "bar".

This will return the index of the first letter of "bar", and return -1 if the string is not found.